# I installed Jupiter and my network manager is gone!

Tags: networking, network-manager, jupiter

I installed Jupiter, everything was goin' fine 'till y restarted my PC. Once it started my network manager was gone so I had no internet connection (neither wifi or ethernet).

I tried everything i found on internet (by using my smartphone) but nothing seemed to work. So I reinstalled Ubuntu 14, the problem obviously solved.

My question is: why did this happen? Does Jupiter damages the network manager or could it be it something else?

Tonight I'll install jupiter again to try to replicate the problem but I'd like to know if somebody else had this problem before.

Thanks!